# Move to Activity when onLoadFinished() doesn't return anything

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider, android-cursoradapter, android-cursor

I have an `onLoadFinished()` implemented as:

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0)
    {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            long userIDFromContentProvider = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(userIDColumn));
            String userEmailFromContentProvider = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(userEmailColumn));

            result.append("\n"+ userEmailFromContentProvider);
            userID = String.valueOf(userIDFromContentProvider);
            userEmail = String.valueOf(userEmailFromContentProvider);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

        if (!result.toString().equals("")) {
            isUserSignedIn = true;
            initUI();
        }

    }
    else
    {
        // Cursor is null.
        moveToMain();
    }
}
```

I need to move user to another activity AFTER `onLoadFinished()` has finished loading without retrieving any data. Turns out, wherever I try to implement it (within the `onLoadFinished()` method), the screen moves to another activity BEFORE the the load has finished. So it runs as:

onLoadFinished() [Cursor count: 0] > move to another activity > onLoadFinished() [Cursor count: 1]

I want it to run as:

onLoadFinished() [Cursor count: 0] > [no data found] > move to another activity.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: onLoadFinished is supposed to be called when the load is... finished. As there is nothing in your code sample to redirect to another activity, are you sure you're not redirecting the user somewhere else in your code?

Comment: @Eselfar that makes sense. But onLoadFinished seems to be run every time there is a change in the data. I want to move to the activity where there's no more data to load anymore. I've now included in OP where I tried moving to another activity.